# Java logback nested variable substitution

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a logging statement like so:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);

long elapsedTime = 8348; //test value
LOGGER.info("message:{},timestamp:{}",
                "Finished execution in {} milliseconds", elapsedTime,
                LocalDateTime.now());
```

I want the first 2 `{}` to be replaced by the string message and the localdatetime. But the third `{}` inside the message should be replaced by the long. So it should log:

```
INFO  app.Foo - message:Finished execution in 8348 milliseconds,timestamp:2016-03-25T13:55:05.026
```

But instead it logs:

```
INFO  app.Foo - message:Finished execution in {} milliseconds,timestamp:5017
```

Any way to have nested variable substitution for logging? I could concatenate the strings like so

```
long elapsedTime = 8348; //test value
LOGGER.info("message:{},timestamp:{}",
                "Finished execution in " + elapsedTime + " milliseconds",
                LocalDateTime.now());
```

But I want to avoid tediously concatenating.

Comment: You have 3 {} in your formatted string, but only 2 arguments after that, every {} should be matched by following argument.

Comment: @DennisR right I understand why the result is the way it is but I'm trying to see how I can have nested variable substitution.

Comment: it is probably not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work that way as the message value is simply replaced and not parsed. The var arg parameters are for the main message format.

I can think of following two options.

```
LOGGER.info("message:Finished execution in {} milliseconds,timestamp:{}", elapsedTime,
 LocalDateTime.now());
```

OR

```
LOGGER.info("message:{},timestamp:{}", String.format("Finished execution in %s milliseconds",
 elapsedTime), LocalDateTime.now());
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked Logback 1.1.5

```
ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent
```

and argumentArray in it. And

```
org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat
```

Nesting is not supported, only array of objects in additional arguments.
 I think the same applies to Log4j.